# Debug not working in Visual Studio 2015 RC 2 with .net 5 MVC 6

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2015

Having an issue after I installed RC 2 from RC 1 where variables declared inside methods can not be inspected in the watch window or by hover. Its driving me crazy I have even re-installed visual studio and repaired multiple times with no luck. Below is a screen shot of an out of the box mvc 6 template with 2 lines added to the home controller to demonstrate the issue. If anyone has seen this or has any ideas how to fix it I would love to try them.
As you can see the watch has no idea what variable 'y' is yet I can look at other variables that are not declared inside the method such as 'User'.
[image]

Comment: .net 5 ???????????????

Comment: yes ??????????????????????

Comment: .NET 5 does not exist yet... so how?

Comment: https://get.asp.net/
Its in RC

Comment: that is ASP.NET 5, not .NET 5...

Comment: my bad, im sure that was super confusing and you had no idea what I was talking about.

Comment: No problem :) But I dont expect it a CTP even this year.

Answer (score 4):

Checking the following box fixed it for now, only took 2 days of wasted time. 
[image]